# I want to rsync a folder from local ubuntu harddrive to raspberry external harddrive

Tags: ssh, raspberrypi, rsync

I want to rsync a folder from local ubuntu harddrive to raspberry external harddrive.

Problem is finding the right path.

When i search in ubuntu file explorer i can open the folder on the raspberry external harddrive
When i copy the path "smb://raspberrypi.local/toon/" from the file explorer to the terminal i get
"bash: smb://raspberrypi.local/toon/: No such file or directory"

When i do the same on my wife's macbook i can also open the folder on the raspberry external harddrive,
but when i choose right mouse click i can choose open in terminal on the macbook, that gives the path
"Volumes/Toon" to the raspberry external harddrive and when i copy that path on the ubuntu computer it does not work.
"bash: Volumes/Toon: No such file or directory"

Can somebody help me howto get the path to the raspberry external harddrive so that i can get to there
from the ubuntu terminal?

Comment: I don't use smb (Samba) shares myself but you could create a directory (mount point) somewhere and then mount the Samba share to that location, then you would just use your mount point directory in your rsync. Search here or web for how to mount Samba share via command line or permanently. One guide is here but it may be outdated: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountWindowsSharesPermanently

Comment: Thank you. I going to try this.

Answer (score 1):

When you rsync between systems, you do not want to use SMB. That's for mounting the file system over the network. Instead, rsync runs one process at each end - which communicates. This means that file checksumming doesn't consume network bandwidth for instance.

Thus what you want to do is

`rsync local/folder/ raspberrypi.local:/path/to/remote/folder`

The path on the RPi should correspond to the actual file system path, and not what is shown by SMB or anything else.

Comment: Thank you. I going to try this.

Comment: In addition to vidario's excellent answer, you may wish to consider using a graphical package such as `luckyBackup` (downloadable from Ubuntu Software) which should make the process more intuitive